# open html link by clicking on point python plotly

Tags: python, html, plotly

I have graph line+markers using Plotly and a list of Html links corresponding to point. how can I embed it in the graph? so the link can be open by clicking on the point.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite straight-forward unfortunately but this link should help.

[https://chart-studio.plotly.com/~chris/2540/hover-over-the-points-to-see-the-link/#plot](https://chart-studio.plotly.com/%7Echris/2540/hover-over-the-points-to-see-the-link/#plot)

Essentially you are calling `text` on your Scatter and passing through `<a>` tags.